# iPad App: Customize the default navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

Umm I am not sure what the title should be.

I am developing an iPad app. My app will have the following hierarchy.

[image]

'Front Page' is simply a page (view controller) for user to choose language. After choosing the language, 'Menu Page' view controller is displayed.

Starting from Menu page and ALL view controllers (VC) in below, the page layout is something like this.

[image]

As you can see, there are top menu and bottom menu. Clicking on the buttons the app will quickly jump to the corresponding view controller (3rd level in the tree, VC1,VC2,VC3 etc) . And for every view, there is a BACK button on every page, clicking which will back to the parent view controller.

I was thinking to implement this by using a tab bar view controller and a navigation view controller but I still do not have a clear idea how to implement this.

Or maybe should I just use the navigation view controller and hide the top tool bar except the back button, and display an overlay UIView as menu which is on top of all other UIViews.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Since this is the outermost container for my app I hope to do it properly at start..

Sorry for my long question.

Comment: Do anyone have any idea on, how to control the height of the status bar that is where the 'back button' is present in above picture. To control the height of that horizontal block where the back button is present and the other v1 presents at the top of the layout.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of view transitions do you want to use and how do you want to update buttons in top and bottom bars.

If you want common navigational transition, you may use navigationController at the root. For buttons in bottom bar, you may use toolBar.

However, if you want to keep using tabbarController, it is strongly discouraged to use navigationController as root and push different tabbarControllers. In other words, revise your tree of viewControllers to keep tabbarController as root.

The most important decision you should make is what kind of container controller you want to use as root controller. Based on my experience, navigationController is most flexible to realized your work flow.

If you would like to, you can create your own container controller:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

It's not too difficult than it seems, unless you want to avoid implementing view transitions.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to make navigation bar hidden throughout and use toolbar with customized buttons

Answer (score 1):

At last I decided to write my own container view controller which is similar to the default navigation controller with custom toolbars on the top and bottom.

I spent a whole night reading the official IOS guide about UIViewController and have a much  clear understanding about how to write it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Turn out that it is not so difficult to implement it